# jQuery: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, togglebutton

I've been trying to get this to toggle two .pngs on button click. When I run the code, console throws an error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<h1>My Website</h1>

<div>
<button data-file="bs">BMW </button>
<button data-file ="ms">Mercedes</button>
</div>

<div id="bmw">
<img src="bmw.png">
</div>

<div id="mercedes">
<img src="merc.png">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

(function () {
    var link = $('link');
    $('button').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this)
        car = $(this).data('file');
        console.log(car);
        link.attr('href', car + '.png');
    });
})();
</script>
```

Which object is this referring to? And how do I alter the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are looking for an object with the tag name link?

Comment: What source line does it throw the error on?

Comment: FYI, I don't see any such error here: http://jsfiddle.net/j1ndk3r8/.  The code doesn't appear to actually do anything useful because it isn't doing anything to the actual `<img>` tags.  You seem to be targeting `$('link')` which is not in the HTML you disclose.

Comment: This : `car = $(this).data('file')` should probably be `car = $(this).attr('data-file')` at least.

Comment: @Shikkediel - nope.  `.data('file')` will read the attribute.  There is no need for `$(this).attr('data-file')`.  That's how `.data()` works.

Comment: Indeed, just googled my way to that...

Answer (score 1):

$('link') is invalid. There is no HTML tag called 'link'.
What you might want to do is

```
<button data-image-id='bmw'>BMW</button>
<button data-image-id='merc'>Mercedes</button>

<img src='bmw.png' id='bmw' />
<img src='merc.png' id='merc' />

(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var button = $(this);
        var imageId = button.data('image-id');
        var image = $('img#' + imageId);
        image.toggle();
    });
})();
```

When a button is clicked, it gets the button's data-image-id, finds the image with that id and toggle the image.